# Using Python Tkinter: How to smoothly move and resize the non focusable window?

Tags: python, winapi, tkinter, pywin32

I created a non focusable window using Tkinter:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import win32api
import win32con
import pywintypes

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("+0+0")
root.lift()


hWindow = pywintypes.HANDLE(int(root.frame(), 16))
exStyle = win32con.WS_EX_COMPOSITED | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED | win32con.WS_EX_NOACTIVATE
win32api.SetWindowLong(hWindow, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle)

root.mainloop()
```

In Delphi In order to smoothly move and resize it, I use the code:

```
procedure TForm1.WMMoving(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  Rect: ^TRect;
begin
  Rect := Pointer(Msg.LParam);
  SetWindowPos(Form1.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, Rect^.left, Rect^.top,
    Rect^.right - Rect^.left, Rect^.bottom - Rect^.top, 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.WMSizing(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  Rect: ^TRect;
begin
  Rect := Pointer(Msg.LParam);
  SetWindowPos(Form1.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, Rect^.left, Rect^.top,
    Rect^.right - Rect^.left, Rect^.bottom - Rect^.top, 0);
end;
```

I need it to create a onscreen keyboard.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using a normal Tkinter window here?

Comment: The reason is that when you click on the window, the focus should not be transferred to this window.

Comment: Are you aware that you can pop up tkinter windows without sending the focus to them?